# Why would my encrypted password no longer allow access after a power outage?

Tags: systemd, system-settings, password-recovery

My desktop has been running Ubuntu 16.10 for some time now

Yesterday my town experienced a terrific thunderstorm and I experienced a power outage / surge that shut off all electronics

When repowering my desktop, the cryptsetup password to unlock my disk sds3_crypt failed repeatedly.

On screen I got the message:

```
cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?

By hitting F1 I get the command prompt screen (possibly incomplete) that displays the following lines:

[       3.929106] kfd kfd: error getting iommu info. is the iommu enabled?
[       3.929138] kfd kfd: Error initializing iommuv2 for device  (1002:130f)
[        3.929270] kfd kfd: device  (1002:130f)  NOT added due to errors
    WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
    Volume group  "ubuntu-vg" not found
    Cannot process volumee group ubuntu-vg
No key available with this passphrase.
No key available with this passphrase.
No key available with this passphrase.

Please unlock disk sda3_crypt***
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Did the outage/surge do something to my system?

Is there a way to restore access?

Comment: Not sure but I have noticed that the numbers lock and caps lock lights on my keyboard turn off when the log in screen for Ubuntu is displayed.

Comment: Tried both, first settings in UEFI, didn't work.  Then entered iommu=soft for Grub entry *Ubuntu, Cntrl + X failed to reboot system  (produced x's instead of rebooting) but F10 did reboot system with edit, still failed to allow entry and password still fails to gain access

Comment: Also, num lock and caps lock lights both work UNTIL Ubuntu initializes and asks for crypt password, then neither work

Comment: Sorry guys, I know others might have has this same problem, but I couldn't wait.   I reformatted my HDD and installed Ubuntu 17.04 ... thank you to thise who tried to help!  And I will be watching for bug fixes on 17.04, as well!  LOL, already getting a >> must enter password for Security System Device! error!  Might be related, but for now, I can work on my computer, so I just ignore!